# Greatest Common Factor

Tags: c++, function, greatest-common-divisor

so I tried to make a function to find a GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) for my friend who just started learning C++ (I have some basic knowledge of C++). So here's my code:

```
int gcd(int var1, int var2){
    int result;
    if(var1<1 || var2<1){
        return 0; //means error
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<=var1 && i<=var2; i++){
            if((var1%i) == 0 && (var2%i) == 0){
                result = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It compiled, but the problem is the .exe stopped working whenever it tries to use the operator '%'. In this case, at this line of code: `var1%i` and `var2%i`. So, I tried to tweak the code a little bit into this:

```
int gcd(int var1, int var2){
    int result;
    if(var1<1 || var2<1){
        result = 0; //means error
    } else {
        for(int i=var1; i>=1; i--){
            if((var1%i) == 0 && (var2%i) == 0){
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And it worked without any problem. So, I was wondering what is the problem with the first code?

Comment: well, n % 0 does not look like something computable, does it?

Comment: In the code, you are starting with int i = 0; and then using var mod 0. The result is undefined as it is a divide by zero error.

Comment: @Mr.Llama cause I erased that part and the .exe works just fine

Comment: @Lao yes... I wonder why I didn't spot that mistake

Comment: @ShyamalDesai yup, thx for the response. I was stupid for not realizing that haha

Comment: @ user3429874: No need to beat yourself up. Programming humbles us all. Enjoy the journey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't % by 0 because it will generate a divide-by-zero exception.  You need to start i at 1 instead of 0 in the first loop.

Comment: ah... thx. now excuse me, while I gather my confidence back for not noticing that stupid mistake. But seriously, thx. I don't know why I didn't realize that haha